# Custom WHM PORT

Tags: linux, centos, hosting

I saw many webhosting companies are changing [**`WHM`**](http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/) **Port** and limiting it's access with the **`browser user-agent`** to be only accesses by a specific `user-agent`.

They are using *`User Agent switcher`* addon via Firefox and type this specific `user-agent` to access [**`WHM`**](http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/).

How can i do this .?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about changing the port. It might best to use port-redirection (i.e. forward 0.0.0.0:1234 to localhost:2087 and drop all packets from the outside net to ports 2086/7).

To achieve the UA protection of your WHM, I would use the [string matching in IPTables](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.18) Here's it in use (for a different purpose): http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/w00tw00t.html

I would set a deny by default rule, then allow anyone who has the string with the `User-Agent` that you require. While IP tables will match the entire packet (i.e. it won't specifically look at the `User-Agent` field of the  request), if you make the string specific enough, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting access based on `user-Agent` is not reliable at all. This is simply because anyone can set the `user-agent` to anything. There is also a firefox addon that enables you to type whatever you want to be sent as user-agent in your requests.

Comment: While this might be true, it doesn't answer the original question.  Better to explain how to achieve it and also why it's not useful in the long term, than just provide an answer saying don't do this?

Comment: @EightBitTony: Saying don't do this will be good if the OP is asking for something unreliable or risky.

Comment: @Khaled Merci, Do you have an idea for how to do it ?

Comment: @EightBitTony Do you have an idea for how to do this ?

Comment: I disagree - the UA protection is a nice way to prevent randomised brute-force attacks. I am assuming that the server admin will *define* a special (fictional) UA and only if they get a matching one, provide them with a login screen. Since this will only add a layer of security, it can't be a bad thing.

Comment: @JayShah: I can write a malicious code that sets the user-agent to the one set by mozilla firefox. So, this is not really a security.

Comment: @Khaled: We are not talking about Mozilla Firefox's UA. We are talking about a custom one. For example, `Mozilla/5.0 (JayShahSomeWebHostingCompany)`. How would you guess `JayShahSomeWebHostingCompany` if I didn't tell you?